# Difference in the order in IF conditions

Tags: php

I read often in examples and some codes this order in if conditions:

```
if (false === $var)
if (null  === $var)
```

instead of

```
if ($var === false)
if ($var === null)
```

What is the main difference? Which one should i preffer?

Comment: Both are similar. You can go for any one of it.

Answer (score 3):

These are called Yoda Conditions.  The "advantage" being you can not accidentally assign a value to a variable when checking its value.
An example would be:

if( 100 = $var ) would give you a syntax error.  So the argument is that Yoda Conditions guarantee youre in fact checking a value and not setting a value.  [This pretty much sums it up.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

Answer (score 0):

Base in my knowledge, this is the preferred syntax for today.

```
if (false === $var)
if (null  === $var)
```

Because when you accidentally get a typo like this:

```
if ($var = false)
```

Which you assigned **false** to the variable **$var**, it's hard to trace this bug when you are running your code.

Comment: The other hassle is when you have that typo, it doesn't generate any errors. That's why it's hard to trace it. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if (false === $var)
if (null  === $var)

This is the preferred and best way of checking the values in if conditions
Because if we use the

$var === false

manual typing errors like

$var = false might accidentally assign value false to the variable $var and will be undetectable.

in case of false= $var the compiler will throw a definite error and we can identify the bug easily